# Surround every line with single quote except empty lines

Tags: unix, awk, sed, text-processing

My goal is to add a single apostrophe to every line in the file and skip empty lines.

**file.txt**:

```
Quote1
Quote2

Quote3
```

So far I have used sed:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/"
```

Which does the job but creates apostrophes also in empty lines:

```
'Quote1'
'Quote2'
''
'Quote3'
```

**My goal:**

```
'Quote1'
'Quote2'

'Quote3'
```

How could I achieve this by using sed, or maybe it should it be awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.*` means `zero or more characters`, you want `1 or more characters` which in any sed would be `..*`:

```
$ sed "s/..*/'&'/" file
'Quote1'
'Quote2'

'Quote3'
```

You can also write that regexp as `.\+` in GNU sed, `.\{1,\}` in POSIX seds, and `.+` in GNU or OSX/BSD sed when invoked with `-E`.

The above assumes lines of all blanks should be quoted. If that's wrong then:

```
$ sed "s/.*[^[:blank:]].*/'&'/" file
'Quote1'
'Quote2'

'Quote3'
```

In any awk assuming lines of all blanks should be quoted:

```
$ awk '/./{$0="\047" $0 "\047"}1' file
'Quote1'
'Quote2'

'Quote3'
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk 'NF{$0="\047" $0 "\047"}1' file
'Quote1'
'Quote2'

'Quote3'
```

You can see the difference between the above with this:

```
$ printf '   \n' | sed "s/..*/'&'/"
'   '
$ printf '   \n' | sed "s/.*[^[:blank:]].*/'&'/"

$ printf '   \n' | awk '/./{$0="\047" $0 "\047"}1'
'   '
$ printf '   \n' | awk 'NF{$0="\047" $0 "\047"}1'

$
```

Comment: I would be tempted to write `sed "/[^[:blank:]]/s/.*/'&'/"` -- a bit tidier I think.

Comment: @glennjackman idk, I just use sed for `s/old/new/`, anything fancier than that I use awk.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
awk '$1{$0 = q $0 q}1' q="'" file
```

Add quotes only if 1st column(`$1`) has some value. `1` to print every line.

Comment: Assigning values to variables in the arg list clutters up ARGV and makes those variables unavailable in the BEGIN section which can bite you if/when you need that later. The **only** time to do that is when you need to assign variables different values between files listed there, e.g. `awk '...' FS=':' file1 FS='@' file2`. Assign variables with `-v var=val` unless you need escape sequences to not be expanded and then use `ENVIRON[]` or store just the value in `ARGV[]`. See examples a, d, and f at http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Comment: Oh, and `$1{...}` would not escape any lines that start with `0`. The way to test for an empty line is `NF{...}` or `/./{...}` depending on your FS value and whether or not a line of blank chars is considered empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add the single quotes to lines that contain nothing but whitespace:

```
sed -E "/./s/(.*)/'\1'/"
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed "/./s/.*/'&'/" file`?

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`

```
sed '/^$/!{s/^/\x27/;s/$/\x27/}' file
```

The above script says

- Look for an empty line - `/^$/` - pattern.
- For those lines that doesn't follow the above pattern(`!`), substitute start(`^`) and end(`$`) with single quotes(`\x27`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` to check for a negative lookbehind, asserting that you won't match an "empty" line:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!$)(.*)/"\1"/' file
```

Another alternative is being more specific in your regex, as @edmorton suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E "s/\S+/'&'/" file.txt
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @nircraft adding an explanation for this would be like adding a comment to `i++` - completely useless. When you're looking at posts that the automated tool put on the **possibly** low quality queue, if you don't know the domain then then you can't help identify the answers that really are low quality vs those that are just fine as code-only, for example, so just move on to the next thing on the list.